# windows xp sound does not come up after stand by mode!

Tags: windows-xp

My computer (windows xp) doesn't play sounds when my computer comes out of standby. It 
does play sound if I restart my computer.  Does anyone have any ideas how to fix 
this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Code 32 from [Microsoft KB Article 310123](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310123):

> > A driver (service) for this device has been disabled. An alternate driver may be providing this functionality. (Code 32)
>
> ### Cause
>
> The start type for this driver is set to disabled in the registry.
>
> ### Recommended resolutions
>
> Reinstall the driver for this device. If this does not work, you might have to change the device start type parameter in the registry.
>
> ### Uninstall and reinstall the driver
>
> Uninstall the driver from Device Manager, and then scan for new hardware to install the driver again.
>
> You may be prompted to provide the path of the driver. Windows may have the driver built-in, or may still have the driver files installed from the last time that you set up the device. However, sometimes, it will open the New Hardware Wizard which may ask for the driver. If you are asked for the driver and you do not have it, you can try to download the latest driver from the hardware vendor’s Web site.
>
> 1. On the device Properties dialog box, click the `Driver` tab, and then click `Uninstall`. Follow the instructions.
> 2. Restart your computer.
> 3. Open Device Manager, click `Action`, and then click `Scan for hardware changes`. Follow the instructions.
>
> ### Change the start type in the Registry
>
> This content is designed for an advanced computer user.
>
> As a last resort, you can edit the registry directly if the driver is required, and if reinstalling or upgrading does not work. Change the start type inside the registry by using Registry Editor. For more information, see the Registry Reference in the Microsoft Windows 2000 Server Resource Kit at the following Microsoft Web site:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/reskit